# Why can't I access /var/run/docker.sock despite being Jenkins user within docker's group?

Tags: docker, jenkins, permissions, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I have Jenkins on Docker, both Jenkins master and slave are Docker containers, with mounted var/run/docker.sock. There is proper connection between them, but when I try to run simple docker "hello-world" as a test (using a Pipeline script), I got famous:

> Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon
>   socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get
>   http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.39/containers/json?all=1: dial
>   unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied

I've read many times, that my Jenkins user should belong to docker group, then everything shoud work just fine. But apparently, this happens:

```
jenkins@7401675c7c9e:~$ groups
jenkins docker
jenkins@7401675c7c9e:~$ docker ps -a
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.39/containers/json?all=1: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

Now I completely don't know what am I doing wrong, I've tried everything:

1. adding `RUN usermod -a -G docker jenkins` to both Dockerfiles (for
   master and slave images)
2. adding `DOCKER_OPTS=' -G jenkins'` to /etc/default/docker
3. adding `privileged: true` to docker-compose
4. manually entering containers and using `usermod -aG docker jenkins`, and relogging later.

No matter what I do, pipeline can't just access docker socket. I am jenkins user, I am in docker group and I still can't do anything with docker daemon. Jenkinsfile is really simple:

```
pipeline{
        agent{
          node{
            label 'swarm'
          }
        }  
        stages {
                stage("Just checking"){
                  steps{
                    sh 'whoami'
                    sh 'groups jenkins'
                  }
                }
                stage("Hello world!"){
                  steps{
                    sh 'docker run hello-world'
                  }
                } ...
```

And results are:

```
+ whoami   
jenkins

+ groups jenkins    
jenkins : jenkins docker

+ docker run hello-world  
docker: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.35/containers/create: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied.  
See 'docker run --help'.  
script returned exit code 126
```

I'm just starting to use docker and jenkins and I have no idea what I am doing wrong, does anybody see any obvious mistake?

Comment: Have you verified docker is running? `service docker status`

Comment: Try using the official Docker Pipeline plugin instead of a raw CLI.

Comment: @mchawre it's strange because `service docker status` returns `[FAIL] Docker is not running ... failed!` but when I try to run `dockerd` I get  `Failed to load listeners: can't create unix socket /var/run/docker.sock: device or resource busy`. 
Somehow I can run other docker commands from inside container and they work (like `docker run` or `docker ps` - I have no idea what's going on

Comment: @MattSchuchard I use BlueOcean plugin to run pipeline scripts, I've got installed Docker Pipeline but I don't see any GUI for that in my Jenkins